# Autofac type registered on a keyed enum with a constructor not resolving

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

Currently we have a container registration for our types:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<FirstClass>().Keyed<IClass>(EnumType.First);
builder.RegisterType<SecondClass>().Keyed<IClass>(EnumType.Second);
...
```

When we resolve this with a default constructor (no constructor), it works perfectly.

The wrapper constructor where the IIndex is passed through:

```
public SomeWrapperClass(ISomeRepo repo, IIndex<EnumType, IClass> classTypes)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _classTypes = classTypes;
    }
```

then we resolve it in a method like this:

```
private object DoSomething(EnumType enumType, SomeParameter someParameter)
    {
        var resolvedItem = _extractTypes[enumType];
        return resolvedItem .GenerateExtract(someParameter);
    }
```

But if we add a constructor with a parameter to our IClass type it fails to find it, we have tried to force it in several ways, including using the with parameter and with constructor keywords when building our container.

The constructor we add looks something like this:

```
public class ClassImplementation: IClass
{
    private readonly IAnotherClassInterface _dependency;

    public ClassImplementation(IAnotherClassInterface secondClass)
    {
        _dependency = secondClass;
    }
}
```

Are we doing something wrong or should it rather not be done this way at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an Visual Studio issue where the project built but it had a reference issue.  After restarting re-sharper and visual studio we added the missing dll and the type was resolved using the with constructor keyword like:

```
builder.RegisterType<ClassImplementation>()
                .UsingConstructor(typeof (IAnotherClassInterface ))
                .Keyed<IClass>(EnumType.First);
```

Comment: Is the `IAnotherClassInterface` constructor set up to be resolvable?

Comment: @mduminy it is just a standard constructor and it will be resolvable if you were to use a non keyed approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expert and I haven't tested this, but as a stab in the dark have you tried:

```
builder.Register(c => new SecondClass(c.Resolve<IDependency>()).Keyed<IClass>(EnumType.Second);
```

This assumes `IDependency` is something that is resolvable.

Comment: Thanks Mike, turns out the issue was a VS2012, resharper on a slow PC issue.  The way we resolved it is in my answer.